# How to use Nginx proxy_pass to pass a subdir to another subdir in different port?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

How can I use proxy_pass in Nginx to pass a subdir to another subdir in different port?

For example, when a user goes to `http://a.com/dashboard/widgets/clock/images/clock.png`, Nginx will pass it to `http://a.com:1234/widgets/clock/images/clock.png`.

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look at the [`proxy_pass`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) directive, which can rewrite and pass request URIs to the backend as well. From the Nginx documentation:

> A request URI is passed to the server as follows:
>
> - If the proxy_pass directive is specified with a URI, then when a request is passed to the server, the part of a normalized request URI
>     matching the location is replaced by a URI specified in the directive:
>
>   ```
>   location /name/ {
>       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1/remote/;
>   }
>   ```
> - If proxy_pass is specified without a URI, the request URI is passed to the server in the same form as sent by a client when the original
>     request is processed, or the full normalized request URI is passed
>     when processing the changed URI:
>
>   ```
>   location /some/path/ {
>       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
>   }
>   ```

So if the URI you're passing to the backend is the same, minus the `/dashboard/` part, your config could look something like this:

```
# Proxy URIs matching '/dashboard/widgets' to 'localhost:1234/widgets'
location /dashboard/widgets {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234/widgets;
}
```

Or you can remove the `widgets` part to proxy everything under `/dashboard/` to `localhost:1234/`. It would just depend on how specific you want the match to be.